# How Do I move a dbt project I created on my desktop into GitHub Online

Tags: dbt

I created a dbt project on my desktop, using dbt CLI and VS Code. I want to move this new folder to GitHub so I can use GitHub as my repo for the dbt project. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new repository on GitHub:

- Visit https://github.com and sign in to your account.
- Click the "+" icon in the upper right corner, then select "New repository."
- Enter a repository name, choose whether it should be public or private, and add an optional description. I'd suggest not to initialise the repository with a README, .gitignore, or license file, since you already have a local repository.
- Click "Create repository."

2. Open a command prompt or terminal on your local machine and navigate to your local Git repository. If you have not already initialised your local directory as a Git repository, do so by running `git init`
3. Add the remote GitHub repository to your local repository by executing the following command `git remote add origin <remote_repository_url>`. Replace `<remote_repository_url>` with the URL of your newly created GitHub repository. You can find this URL in the "Quick setup" section on the GitHub repository page.
4. Verify that the remote repository has been added successfully by running `git remote -v`. This command will show the URLs of the remote repositories connected to your local repository.
5. Push your local commits to the remote GitHub repository by running `git push -u origin main`. Replace `main` with the name of your local branch if it is not called "main." This command will push your local commits to the remote repository and set the upstream tracking branch for future push and pull operations.

This should be it. If you already have a local git repo, you can skip step 2.